# How to retrieve info out of JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I build a scraper with Python. It works when I place an static URL, but I would like to make a for each URL loop with a JSON file.

This code returns an error, KeyError. I red online that this happens because its an object and not an array. I'm not sure how to fix this. Could someone point me in the right way or maybe even review the code? I placed some screenshots of the errors, the way i look up the JSON info and the way the JSON file is structured.

JSON structure:

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

with open("C:\data.json") as my_json:
    json_dict = json.load(my_json)
for website in json_dict[0][0]:
    print("About to scrape: ", website)


print('step 1')
#get url
page_link = website
print('step 2')
#open page
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=1)
print('step 3')
#parse page
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
print('step 4')
#Find info
naam = page_content.find_all(class_='<random class>')[0].decode_contents()
print('step 5')
#Print
print(naam)
```

Comment: `for website in json_dict['url'][0]['loc']:`

Comment: You shouldnt use images for code. You should include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, your code gives the error as well:
  for website in json_dict['url'][0]['loc']:
KeyError: 'url

Comment: Is there anything in the JSON file before what you showed in the screenshot? Can you post the JSON as plain text instead of an image?

Answer (score -1):

In your json file, the opening bracket of the whole thing is unnamed, try naming it data, then call it with `json_dict['data']['url']['loc'][0]` (for the url itself)

Comment: Before you add a comment saying it didn't work, I just added a [0] to the end of the expression since I didn't realize you're using an array in the json file (for whatever reason)

Comment: I'm glad I refreshed. :-) Unfortunately, this gave an error as well.
$ python c:/Users/Sebastiaan/Desktop/PythonBoek/scraperPython/scraper2.0.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Sebastiaan/Desktop/PythonBoek/scraperPython/scraper2.0.py", line 8, in <module>
    for website in json_dict['data']['url']['loc'][0]:
KeyError: 'data'

I changed my json file like you requested. 

{
  "data": {
    "url": [
      {
        "loc": [
          "<privacy>"
        ],
        "changefreq": [
          "daily"
        ]
      },

Comment: I meant in your json doing data = { ... not {data :

Comment: it wouldnt be a valid `json` file if it contained `data={...}`

Comment: the ... was a placeholder lmao

Comment: @TylerT I dont know understand. **In your json file, the opening bracket of the whole thing is unnamed, try naming it data...** - naming it data would mean its no longer valid json.

Comment: adding data= breaks the json file. It's not helping, i'm sorry. I know you are trying to help.

Comment: Can you edit the answer to show precisely what you mean by adding a name?